# A question on regular local rings (of positive characteristic ) of dimension $2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, positive-characteristic, regular-rings

Let $R$ be a [regular local ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_local_ring) of dimension $2$ and of characteristic $p>0$.

How to show that for every $f_1,f_2,f_3 \in R$, $\exists 0\ne c\in R$ and $n_0\in \mathbb N$ such that $c(f_1f_2f_3)^{2p^n} \in (f_1^{3p^n}, f_2^{3p^n}, f_3^{3p^n}),\forall n >n_0$ ?

Comment: Where is this question coming from?

Comment: @Youngsu: Well, I'm trying to show that in any regular local ring, of dimension $2$, $(f_1f_2f_3)^2 \in (f_1^3,f_2^3,f_3^3)$ for every $f_1,f_2,f_3$. The problem can be reduced to positive characteristic. Now for regular local rings of positive characteristic, an ideal is equal to its tight closure, and being in the tight closure is same as what I am asking for ...